# CSS inside of regular 'ol text

Tags: html, css, formatting

I feel like this is something that should be an easy fix, but I'm stumped.
I'd like to have each item in the list separated (inline) by a "list-block", but I can't get the blocks to show up using anything other than div tags, which automatically jump to a new line. I would just use HTML symbols (like below), but I want CSS customization. Thanks in advance!

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sos12/UwsFL/

CSS:

```
.list-block {
  width: 1%;
  height:0;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
  -moz-border-radius: 1%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1%;
  border-radius: 1%;
  background: black;
}
```

Tags:

```
<h2>
   Apples 
      <i class="list-block"></i>
   Pears
      <div class="list-block"></div>
   Peaches
      <span class="list-block"></span>
   Plums 
      <a class="list-block"></a>
   Grapes  
</h2>
```

HTML symbols:

```
<h2>
  Apples 
    &diams;
  Pears
    &diams;
  Peaches
    &diams;
  Plums 
    &diams;
  Grapes  
</h2>
```

Comment: So what do you want it to look like?

Comment: Apples ♦ Pears ♦ Peaches ♦ Plums ♦ Grapes (but with CSS instead of HTML diamonds)

Comment: So you want diamonds, not squares?

Comment: It doesn't matter. The diamonds were just convenient. I only care about the actual ability to put the CSS there in the first place, if that makes sense.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! I'd upvote your help...if I could. Good Karma, is good Karma, right? :)

Comment: Yeah. No problem. Welcome to S.O.! It's always a pleasure to welcome new users who ask good questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the elements to be on the same line and have the attributes of a block element (such as a div), you have to use `display: inline-block`. You can then use `margin` to control the spacing between them.:

```
.list-block {
    width: 1%;
    height:0;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
    -moz-border-radius: 1%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1%;
    border-radius: 1%;
    background: black;

    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

---

If you want to rotate the elements to make them diamonds, just use a transform ([note that this is CSS3 and is not supported in really old browsers](http://caniuse.com/transforms2d)):

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
-o-transform: rotate(45deg);
transform: rotate(45deg);
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UwsFL/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:inline-block`.

This will allow you to make `<div>`s show up on the same line, or allow you to give width (and height) to an otherwise inline element.

Answer (score 0):

For the list , usually use list-style-type http://jsfiddle.net/UwsFL/2/

```
li {
    list-style-type:square;
    font-size:2em;/* to show that squares follow font-size */
}
```

But inside a title, ul has no place :).
Your approach with html entities is a good idea , then maybe  you need to use word-spacing ?
http://jsfiddle.net/UwsFL/3/

```
h2 {
    text-align:center;
    word-spacing:1em;
}
```

You can as well use pseudo element and style them :
http://jsfiddle.net/UwsFL/5/ `(only in between)`

```
h2 {
    text-align:center;
}
h2 span {
    display:inline-block;
}
h2 span:before {
    content:'\29eb';
    padding:0 0.5em;
}
h2 span:first-of-type:before {
    content:'';
}
```

or all around : http://jsfiddle.net/UwsFL/6/

Hope these examples give you some idea:)